# Settings cell selected background view removes backgroundview

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uitableview

I'm trying to set up custom `UITableViewCells`. I can set the backgroundView no problem, but if I set `selectedBackgroundView`, the cell's background becomes white and only the selected background is seen:

```
- (void) createCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell onRow: (NSUInteger)row
{
UIImageView* bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background_red.png"]];
cell.backgroundView = bgImage;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgImage;
cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;

UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame) / 2, 200, 50)];
titleLabel.text = [[self.ruleList objectAtIndex: row] objectForKey: TitleKey];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview: titleLabel];

}
```

Comment: because you are setting the same image for both backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView.

Comment: @sreecharan welp that worked. I only did that to test, but apparently bad testing -__- Thank you

Comment: Also you don't set the FRAME OF THE cell or the ImageView. do initWithFrame instead of initWithImage and then imageView.image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the same image for both backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView.

```
cell.backgroundView = bgImage;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgImage;
```

when you do like this, both are overlapped and results in a white colored background or you could see only the background selected view.